# how can I create a debian package to distribute python modules without using distutils?

Tags: python, debian, package, debhelper

I'm getting myself thoroughly confused how to correctly package my [python3 based application](https://github.com/fossfreedom/alternative-toolbar/tree/debian).

My application uses a Makefile to install stuff to the correct file locations e.g.

```
/usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/foo/myfoo.plugin
/usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/foo/myfoo/po/translation.mo
/usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/foo/myfoo_module.py
/usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/foo/myfoo_module2.py
```

I'm not using a python distutils setup.py type installation - just a straightforward `sudo make install` based method.

When I try to Debian package my rules are very straightforward:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
    dh $@ --parallel --with autoreconf,python3

override_dh_autoreconf:
    dh_autoreconf -- ./autogen.sh

override_dh_auto_configure:
    dh_auto_configure -- --libdir="\$${exec_prefix}/lib"
```

My debian/control file "build-depends" is again straightword:

```
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9),
               dh-autoreconf,
               dh-python (>= 1.20130903),
               gir1.2-glib-2.0,
               gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0,
               gir1.2-gtk-3.0,
               gir1.2-peas-1.0,
               gir1.2-rb-3.0,
               gobject-introspection (>= 0.10.0),
               intltool (>= 0.35.0),
               libglib2.0-dev,
               python3
```

That works just fine - I can run `debuild -us -uc` and it creates my .deb and when I install via `sudo dpkg -i myfoo-0.1_all.deb` everything is installed in the correct file locations.

Except one small matter - each python module should be byte-compiled so that on installation there is a subfolder `/usr/lib/rhythbox/plugins/foo/__pycache__` containing `myfoo_module.pyc` and `myfoo_module2.pyc`

Now I know I cannot byte-compile during the build process - Debian rules forbid having a .deb with byte-compiled modules.  So somehow I need to get debhelper to work for me.

Looking at the Debian packaging guide they mention stuff like cdbs, distutils etc - any [debhelper](https://wiki.debian.org/Python/AppStyleGuide) examples always use syntax like:

```
override_dh_auto_install:
        dh_auto_install
        python setup.py install --root=$(CURDIR)/debian/$(DEB_SOURCE) --install-layout=deb)
```

... but I'm not using a distutils setup.py to install my application.

So I'm must be missing something pretty obvious - any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use distutils or a setup.py to create a valid deb for a Python program; `dh_python3` would just make things easier if you *were* using distutils. Since you're not, you should simply proceed as if you were using something other than Python.

Since I don't know exactly what your structure is, I can't describe the exact steps, but in general you should install the right files to the right places with `dh_install` and create appropriate maintainer scripts to do whatever work is necessary for byte-compiling (on install or update) and removing the byte-compiled files (on remove or purge). The maintainer scripts that `dh_python3` produces may provide a good starting point (which you can probably find in most files matching `/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-*.postinst` and `.postrm` on your system).